# Finding the cofactor and determinant of a 3x3 matrix

Tags: java, matrix

In the code listed below I am able to correctly find the sum, multiplication, and transpose of a two matrices. I am unsure how to find the cofactor and determinant going along the same type of set up I have for the other matrices. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

```
public class MatrixMult {

public MatrixMult(int first[][], int second[][], int m, int n, int p, int q) {
    doMatrixMultiply(first, second, m, n, p, q);
}

public void doMatrixMultiply(int first[][], int second[][], int m, int n,
        int p, int q) {

    if (n != p)
        System.out
                .println("Matrices with entered orders can't be multiplied with each other.");
    else {
        int multiply[][] = new int[m][q];
        int addition[][] = new int[m][q];
        int transpose[][] = new int[m][q];
        int transpose2[][] = new int[m][q];
        int cofactor[][] = new int[m][q];

        int mult = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int tran = 0;
        int co = 0;

        for (int c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < q; d++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < p; k++) {
                    mult = mult + first[c][k] * second[k][d];
                }

                multiply[c][d] = mult;
                mult = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Product of entered matrices:-");

        for (int c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < q; d++)
                System.out.print(multiply[c][d] + "\t");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        for (int c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < q; d++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < p; k++) {
                    sum = first[c][d] + second[c][d];
                }

                addition[c][d] = sum;
                sum = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sum of entered matrices:-");

        for (int c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < q; d++)
                System.out.print(addition[c][d] + "\t");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        int c;
        int d;
        for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
                transpose[d][c] = first[c][d];
        }
        for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
                transpose2[d][c] = second[c][d];
        }

        System.out.println("Transpose of first entered matrix:-");

        for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            for (d = 0; d < m; d++)
                System.out.print(transpose[c][d] + "\t");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Transpose of second entered matrix:-");

        for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            for (d = 0; d < m; d++)
                System.out.print(transpose2[c][d] + "\t");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153823/determining-cofactor-matrix-in-java

Comment: I have taken a look at that, but he seems to take a different approach then what I have taken. I am not sure how to apply it to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the implemenation of determinant using your structure for the matrix represantation using the code from the link [Determining Cofactor Matrix in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153823/determining-cofactor-matrix-in-java):

```
public int determinant(int[][] result, int rows, int cols) {
    if (rows == 2)
        return result[0][0] * result[1][1] - result[0][1] * result[1][0];

    int determinant1 = 0, determinant2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        int temp = 1, temp2 = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            temp *= result[(i + j) % cols][j];
            temp2 *= result[(i + j) % cols][rows - 1 - j];
        }

        determinant1 += temp;
        determinant2 += temp2;
    }

    return determinant1 - determinant2;
}
```

and for calculating the cofactor also using the code from the provided link:

```
public int[][] cofactor(int[][] matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    int[][] result = new int[rows][cols];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            result[i][j] = (int) (Math.pow(-1, i + j) * determinant(
                    removeRowCol(matrix, rows, cols, i, j), rows - 1,
                    cols - 1));
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public int[][] removeRowCol(int[][] matrix, int rows, int cols,
        int row, int col) {
    int[][] result = new int[rows - 1][cols - 1];

    int k = 0, l = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (i == row)
            continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (j == col)
                continue;
            result[l][k] = matrix[i][j];

            k = (k + 1) % (rows - 1);
            if (k == 0)
                l++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I was able to find the determinate of the first and second matrix by applying this code. I changed a few things but it was easy to understand.

Comment: did you manage to calculate the cofactor or do you need more help?

Comment: I am still needing help with the cofactor. The link that you posted has been helpful, but I am having a hard time converting the code he has into what I am working with. I found a couple of other sites for finding the cofactor, but my main issue is creating the object in the method seems to not be working(which is what everyone seems to be doing). There has to be a simpler equation?

Comment: No problem, but you should take a look at the link provided in the answer below, your code is not nice regarding object oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search will find you a lot of examples. E.g. http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-java-for-performing-matrix-operations/26800